# Is minus zero (-0) equivalent to zero (0) in C#

Tags: c#

Is minus zero (-0) equivalent to zero (0) in C#?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For integers, there is no binary representation that makes a difference between 0 and -0, so they are by definition equal.

For IEEE floating-point numbers, there is a distinction of negative and positive zero. I made some tests (CLR of .NET Framework 2.0, C# 3) and it seems that they are considered equal, which is actually the behavior expected according to the IEEE 754 standard.

Here's my test code to show that:

```
    double minusOne = -1.0;
    double positiveZero = 0.0;
    double negativeZero = minusOne*positiveZero;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1} -> {2}", positiveZero, negativeZero, positiveZero == negativeZero);
    Console.WriteLine("Binary representation is equal: {0}", BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(positiveZero) == BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(negativeZero));
```

Returns:

```
0 == 0 -> True
Binary representation is equal: False
```

Comment: `double negativeZero = -0.0` also yields the same results, which means that the constant `-0.0` is correctly parsed into the "negative zero" value of a double.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you're looking for the edge cases where they aren't interchangeable, so here are some examples.

### `object.Equals` on `struct`s

```
> struct SomeStruct { public double X; }
> var a = new SomeStruct { X = 0d };
> var b = new SomeStruct { X = -0d };
> a.Equals(b)
false
>
```

### Inversion

```
> 1/0d
∞
> 1/-0d
-∞
>
```

### Explicit byte conversion

Any type of explicit byte-wise or bit-wise deconstruction, of course, or type punning. These examples are from a PC:

```
> BitConverter.GetBytes(0d)
byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
> BitConverter.GetBytes(-0d)
byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128 }
>
```

### `Math.Sign`

Despite what you might expect, `Math.Sign` does *not* distinguish between negative and positive zero. It only tells you whether a number is equal to, greater than, or less than 0.

```
> Math.Sign(-0f)
0
```

### `Math.Min` and `Math.Max`

A few arithmetic operations have edge cases for -0. One interesting one is `Math.Min` (and equivalently for max), which is that when comparing signed zeros it returns the second one. So:

```
> BitConverter.GetBytes(Math.Min(0.0, -0.0))
byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128 }
> BitConverter.GetBytes(Math.Min(-0.0, 0.0))
byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
>
```

### A note on irregular `decimal` representations

The `decimal` type doesn't have a negative 0 per se, but it does have multiple binary representations for zero:

```
> new decimal(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 })
0
> new decimal(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, -2147483648 })
0
>
```

The second example there could be considered a negative zero because it's bitwise-identical to the regular zero except with the negation bit set. But as far as the formatter's concerned it's just a zero. There are, in fact dozens of zero representations for `decimal`, for different decimal point shifts, all of which are arithmetically equivalent and display as 0:

```
> new decimal(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 131072 })
0.00
> new decimal(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 1835008 })
0.0000000000000000000000000000
> new decimal(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 65536 })
0.0
```

That said, you'll only be able to distinguish them from each other by binary-comparison or binary-conversion means. From just experimentation, it seems that the `struct` trick above doesn't work on them. `Math.Min` returns whichever zero was given second.

### Bonus: Subnormal numbers

Certain patterns of bits in `float` and `double` types represent [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subnormal_number) (aka denormal) values. I won't go into what they are—see the link instead—but the important thing to know is that the CLI spec explicitly declares their operations as implementation-specific. I don't *know* that there are platforms that treat them as 0, but there *could* be. On the other hand, *The C# Programming Language* says that they're "considered valid non-zero values".

Comment: Just an interesting tidbit: I accidentally came across diverging behavior of _object.Equals_ / _ValueType.Equals_  with regard to structs containing floating point numbers (as per your 1st code example) while using online .NET sandboxes. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Ideone, which seems to use Mono, does not adhere to the behavior of ValueType.Equals as specified in the [MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_ValueType_Equals_System_Object_) (code example: https://ideone.com/7iWule). DotNetFiddle, when choosing the .NET Core 2.2 compiler, will also show diverging behavior (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Se1U3n). However, switching the compiler in DotNetFiddle to either .NET 4.7.2 or Roslyn 2.0 will produce a result in line with the documented behavior of ValueType.Equals. :-)

Comment: From another Stack Overflow comment by @Dono, looks like that was fixed in Core in [PR 13164](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/13164)

Answer (score 13):

For Decimals, there are at least 4 types of zeros:

```
Decimal zero = Decimal.Zero;
Decimal negativeZero1 = new Decimal(0, 0, 0, true, 0);
Decimal negativeZero2 = -0.0m;
Decimal negativeZero3 = Decimal.Negate(Decimal.Zero);
```

While all are equal and printed out as `"0"`, they have different bit representation:

```
zero:          {0x00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 }
negativeZero1: {0x00000000 00000000 00000000 80000000 }
negativeZero2: {0x00000000 00000000 00000000 80010000 }
negativeZero3: {0x00000000 00000000 00000000 80000000 }
```

Source: [Decimal Negative Zero Representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/decimal-negative-zero-representation-lakshan-fernando?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: +1 - but: your binary `negativeZero1` and `negativeZero3` look pretty much the same to me?

Comment: This isn't quite the whole story: there are actually 256 representations for 0 in `decimal` (give or take a fence-post), about half of which have the sign bit set.

Comment: An interesting point in the linked source: `BTW, C# compiler does not treat “-0m” as negative zero, although it does get both the sign and the scale correctly for “-0.0m”` I've just run into this difference.