# Does the Complex-struct in .NET know which sign 0 has?

Tags: c#, .net, fft, complex-numbers

In python, if I want a complex number 1+0i, then it will be represented as `(1+0j)`; if I want the conjugate, it is represented as `(1-0j)`. On .NET, 1+0i is represented as a tuple of floats, `(1, 0)`, and the Complex struct doesn't seem to show any information regarding whether or not the 0 is "negative."

To account for this, I have been representing 0 values with `Double.Epsilon` since it's close enough as far as I'm concerned, and allows me to essentially have a negative zero.

When I use `Complex.Conjugate(new Complex(1, 0))`, does .NET know that the expression is now 1-0i somewhere under the hood?

Comment: In IEEE floating point, `0==-0`. That negative sign is kind of pointless. Don't worry about it.

Comment: For example, in Python: `a=complex(1,0); a==a.conjugate()` returns `True`.

Comment: Ok, I can't believe I didn't think to just do that. Thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: They're equal but have distinct representations, and you *can* distinguish between them. Just like for `decimal` in C#, 1.0m and 1.00m are equal under `==` but distinct.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I know they have distinct representations. For OP this does not matter. In all my years of numerical computation I've never ran into a situation where this matters. I'd love to learn of a situation where it does. The difference between 1.0 and 1.00 does matter though. Cool that C# can keep track of significant digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between +0 and -0. They have a different bit-representation.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3139636/128081) I've written a unit-test (which passes):

```
[TestMethod]
public void ComplexZeroTest()
{
    Complex c = new Complex(1, 0);
    Complex d = Complex.Conjugate(c);
    Assert.AreEqual(c.Real, d.Real);
    Assert.AreEqual(c.Imaginary, d.Imaginary);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(c.Imaginary), 
                       BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d.Imaginary));
}
```

So the answer to your questions seems to be yes.

Comment: Ok, I knew that +0 and -0 were stored differently in memory, but I couldn't see any proof in the Complex struct that indicated as such. I think this answers my question, thanks!