# Can this double precision rounding error condition ever be reached?

Tags: c#, double, precision

I've found this line of code in the [IronPython fork of the DLR](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr/blob/bdcef9058bd174878afa5291fd2d9d83a1415582/Src/Microsoft.Dynamic/Utils/MathUtils.cs#L195):

```
return value < 0.0 || 1.0 / value < 0.0 ? -0.0 : 0.0;
```

Where `value` is a `double`. There is no covering test case and since `1.0 / double.MaxValue > 0` I'm struggling to see how the `1.0 / value < 0.0` condition could ever be reached.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** 
I mean reached in a meaningful way so that `value < 0.0 == false` and `1.0 / value < 0.0 == true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is to catch the case where `value` is itself `-0.0`. It makes sure that the method returns `-0.0` when the input is `-0.0`.

The condition `-0.0 < 0.0` is false, but `1.0 / -0.0` is `-∞` and `-∞ < 0.0` is true.

Therefore `1.0 / value < 0.0` will evaluate to true when `value` is `-0.0`, whereas `value < 0.0` will result in false.

This is supported by the comment on the line above the one you quoted:

```
// Preserve the sign of the input, including +/-0.0
return value < 0.0 || 1.0 / value < 0.0 ? -0.0 : 0.0;
```

Floating-point numbers are weird, especially in edge-cases like this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139538/is-minus-zero-0-equivalent-to-zero-0-in-c-sharp) for some more insight.

Comment: Beat me by a second. :)

Comment: No need to rub it in. :(

Comment: Right, but then you'll not go into the second branch, that bit of code won't be hit because it is handled by the first condition. The question is how can `1/value` be negative when value is non-negative.

Comment: OK, thanks. Yes, that makes sense, that is the condition they are protecting against.

Comment: Responding to your edit. The return implies a boolean but the tertiary operator returns a double. If anything it's returning a double. The first check will return 1.0 if value is negative, the second check obviously uses the tertiary result.

Comment: @Pickle What do you mean, "*the return implies a boolean*"? The method very much returns a double, see its signature. That tertiary returns `-0.0` if `value` is any negative number, including `-0.0`.

Comment: To be honest I didn't even look at the code linked, just what he posted. The reason I mentioned that though is because i read your updated edit as implying a boolean return rather than an implicit conversion to 0.0 or 1.0. You're fine though, would have been obvious had I actually followed his link.

Comment: @Pickle cool. I still don't follow where you think an implicit conversion is happening

Comment: An implicit conversion IS happening. The first OR is (value < 0) which is a true / false statement while the return is a double, implicitly converting the result from a boolean to a double.

Comment: @Pickle Where do you think that is?

Comment: Sorry, read my edit, accidentally submitted while I was still typing.

Comment: @Pickle You've got the precedence wrong. It reads `return (value < 0.0 || 1.0 / value < 0.0) ? -0.0 : 0.0;` -- that is, if `value < 0.0` OR `1.0 / value < 0.0` then it returns `-0.0`, otherwise it returns `0.0`. There is no implicit conversion from `bool` to `double`.

Comment: Oh, that's embarrassing, you're completely right, my mistake. I misread the order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

It will be negative if value is negative.

`(1 / -0.5) = -2`