# NewtonSoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject does serialize zero to negative zero ( 0 serialized like as -0.0 )

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, .net-5

I have a `ASP.NET 5 Web API` project. And I use `MsSql 2016` database. I get data from database and return it to app via API. But I have a problem. API returns `0` to like as `-0.0` (negative zero)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConfigManager.ConnectionString));

    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<AddXUserIdRequiredHeaderParameter>();
        //c.OperationFilter<AddXLanguageHeaderParameter>();
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyManagerWS", Version = "v1" });

        // Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
}
```

```
public class DbHelper {

        public static GetDataOutput GetData(int userId, GetDataInput input)
        {
            var result = new ReportItemStockDataResponse();

            string sqlQuery = @"SELECT  ItemId,
                                        ItemName,
                                        ItemCode,
                                        Barcode,
                                        ActualAmount,
                                        UnitName,
                                        RealAmount,
                                        SpecialAmount,
                                        ActualAmountWithSecondUnit,
                                        RealAmountWithSecondUnit,
                                        SpecialAmountWithSecondUnit,
                                        SecondUnitName,
                                FROM
                                MyTable";
            try
            {
                using (var connDb = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    connDb.Open();
                    using (var command = connDb.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                result.ItemStockLines.Add(
                                    new ReportItemStockDataResponse.ItemStock()
                                    {
                                           ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ItemId"]),
                                           ItemName = dr["ItemName"].ToString(),
                                           ItemCode = dr["ItemCode"].ToString(),
                                           Barcode = dr["Barcode"].ToString(),
                                           ActualAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dr["ActualAmount"]),
                                           UnitName = dr["UnitName"].ToString(),
                                           RealAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dr["RealAmount"]),
                                           SpecialAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dr["SpecialAmount"]),
                                           ActualAmountWithSecondUnit = Convert.ToDouble(dr["ActualAmountWithSecondUnit"]),
                                           RealAmountWithSecondUnit = Convert.ToDouble(dr["RealAmountWithSecondUnit"]),
                                           SpecialAmountWithSecondUnit = Convert.ToDouble(dr["SpecialAmountWithSecondUnit"]),
                                           SecondUnitName = dr["SecondUnitName"].ToString(),
                                    });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex, "Error");
                result = null;
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

```
var result=DbHelper.GetData();
var serializedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Serialized result like as below:

```
{
    "itemStockLines": [
        {
            "itemId": 111222333,
            "itemCode": "Test code",
            "itemName": "Test item",
            "barcode": "",
            "actualAmount": -0.0,
            "realAmount": -0.0,
            "specialAmount": -0.0,
            "unitName": "ADET",
            "secondUnitName": "QUTU",
            "actualAmountWithSecondUnit": -0.0,
            "realAmountWithSecondUnit": -0.0,
            "specialAmountWithSecondUnit": -0.0
        }
     ]
}
```

But `actualAmount`, `realAmount`, `specialAmount`, `actualAmountWithSecondUnit`, `realAmountWithSecondUnit`, `specialAmountWithSecondUnit` are zero in C# and DB.

**Note**: These are double variable in C#

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson version is 5.0.3**

Thanks for helping

Comment: well: is this floating point? because negative zero **is an actual thing** in floating point; no, really; you could perhaps manually check for that, and change to non-negative zero; you might also want to look at the code that is computing this zero

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for your comment, these are double variable

Comment: It would be nice to see the code how you got  from db original data and how you have serialized

Comment: example of negative zero: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoagMwBsIBDDAAgVYF5W4yBmAAwC0rAJ5dWAgNx1GLVgC8JHAFRiZVImQCcACgbMMAOgCSAZwByMAOYsAlgDcYuhQEpXU1gHovrDLhhqLT0lTm4BD29ffxxAzR0XIwAVCABlfzs8a113Tx8eASA=== - basically, the sign bit is retained from operations (works with both `float` and `double`). If what you have stored in the database is negative zero, then... everything seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I use ```JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);```

Comment: I am sory but DbHelper.GetData();  is not very usefull. Can you post GetData pls?

Comment: FYI - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3139636/11392290

Comment: @Serge I added DbHelper's code

Comment: @RamilAliyev Thanks, it is really helfull, but it would be nice if you add the code where you insert data into db  and ReportItemStockDataResponse class too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I research a few days this problem and I found solution for this problem.

I add just `0.0` (positive zero) to db read's result.

For example:

```
 ActualAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dr["ActualAmount"]) + 0.0
```

I test this solution and it worked fine:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

var str = "-0";

var double1 = Convert.ToDouble(str);

var double2 = Convert.ToDouble(str) + 0.0;

var serializedDouble1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(double1);

var serializedDouble2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(double2);

Console.WriteLine($"serializedDouble1: {serializedDouble1}");
Console.WriteLine($"serializedDouble2: {serializedDouble2}");
```

Result:

[image: result]

**Note**: The best way for this solution, alter the SQL script that insert data to table.

For example:

`INSERT INTO MyTable(ActualAmount) VALUES(@actualAmount + 0.0)`

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

I am not expecting any up or down votes. It is just FYI.

Who wants to learn more about signed zero I can recommend
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3139636/11392290
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

I made this test just for the record. For me the result looks very interesting. I deserialized PO json and the serialized it again using NewtonsoftJson. All  negative zero doubles  are still negative

```
var jsonDeserealized=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
var jsonReversed=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDeserealized);
```

result

```
{
  "itemStockLines": [
    {
      "itemId": 111222333,
      "itemCode": "Test code",
      "itemName": "Test item",
      "barcode": "",
      "actualAmount": -0.0,
      "realAmount": -0.0,
      "specialAmount": -0.0,
      "unitName": "ADET",
      "secondUnitName": "QUTU",
      "actualAmountWithSecondUnit": -0.0,
      "realAmountWithSecondUnit": -0.0,
      "specialAmountWithSecondUnit": -0.0
    }
  ]
}
```

classes

```
public class ItemStockLine
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemCode { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public double actualAmount { get; set; }
    public double realAmount { get; set; }
    public double specialAmount { get; set; }
    public string unitName { get; set; }
    public string secondUnitName { get; set; }
    public double actualAmountWithSecondUnit { get; set; }
    public double realAmountWithSecondUnit { get; set; }
    public double specialAmountWithSecondUnit { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<ItemStockLine> itemStockLines { get; set; }
}
```

if you want to convert from negative zero to pozitive , you can use this code

```
private double ConvertToDouble( string val)
{
    var value=Convert.ToDouble(val);
    return IsNegativeZero(value)? 0.0d : value;
}
private bool IsNegativeZero(double x)
{
    return x == 0.0 && double.IsNegativeInfinity(1.0 / x);
}
```

test

```
var stringValue= "-0";
var value = ConvertToDouble(stringValue); // value= 0
```

you can use it this way

```
 SpecialAmount = ConvertToDouble(dr["SpecialAmount"]),
```