# Difference between C++ and C# hex values for doubles

Tags: c#, c++, .net, byte

I am replacing some C++ code that writes a binary file with C# (net6.0), and I'm noticing an discrepancy between the values written to the file.

If I have a double precision value equal to 0.0, C++ writes the bytes as:

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

However C# (using BinaryWriter) is writing the same value as:

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80`

If I convert 0.0 to bytes using System.BitConverter.GetBytes(), I get all 0x00's. If I convert the bytes with 0x80 to a double using BitConverter, it still gives me 0.0.

```
byte[] zero = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(0.0); // 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
bool equal = 0.0 == System.BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80}); // true
```

This doesn't seem like it will cause any problems, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Looks like you're getting `-0.0`, assuming the `0x80` is the high byte of the double. Is the value the result of a calculation that could end up with a negative sign?

Comment: @AdrianMole There is math going on, and it is theoretically possible.

Comment: @canton7 I had a mistake which has been edited. The class is actually BinaryWriter.

Comment: In fact, other bits (in the exponent) can also be 1 and the value would still [represent -ve zero]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#:~:text=In%20IEEE%20754%20decimal%20floating,the%20sign%20bit%20being%20one).

Comment: To @AdrianMole's point, `-0.0 == 0.0`, so your test will still pass in that case. Try [the things suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739795/how-can-i-test-for-negative-zero) to test for negative zero

Comment: Aha, `BinaryWriter.Write(double)` will blit the double little-endian, so that final `0x80` does represent a sign bit of 1

Comment: OK, I think I know why we're getting negative zero -- I found a line of code that is doing this: double[] x = y.Select(x=> x * -1.0).ToArray(); Some values of the input array are zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, that trailing `0x80` byte is actually the *high* byte of the `double` value. So, the MSB being set in that is the *sign bit*. This means that the number being stored is actually `-0.0` (which, in virtually all cases, compares equal to `0.0`, so it shouldn't cause any problems).

In fact, [there are other bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) (in the *exponent*) that can bet set to 1 but still leave the value of the represented `double` as (+/-) zero.

How did we get `-0.0`? Can't say without seeing the code that generates the value but, from the same Wiki page:

> One may obtain negative zero as the result of certain computations,
> for instance as the result of arithmetic underflow on a negative
> number (other results may also be possible), or −1.0×0.0, or simply as
> −0.0.

Comment: You can see in the comment on the question I found exactly that -- a 0.0 was being multiplied by -1.0.

Comment: @WalterWilliams I would presume that *any* negative value multiplied by 0.0 would also give a -0.0 representation. But I wouldn't like to quote that in a "language-lawyer" context.

Comment: It should be fine. Any math using that value from a reader should still work out correct. I just wanted to make sure I could explain the binary differences.

Comment: @WalterWilliams Yeah. The linked Wiki states that the `==` operator in C and Java will be true for `0.0 == -0.0`. I can't see that C# would be any different. [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3139538/10871073).

Comment: I ran the line of code in the question which tested 0.0 == BitConverter.ToDouble() with the negative zero bytes and it worked fine. So I'm completely satisfied.